# Unit testing after adding database with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, transactions

I've added database functionality using hibernate to a system which was in memory up to this point. When all the data was it the memory I was able to use JUnit which restored the original data after each test.

Is there a way to achieve the same result with the new hibernate addition?
By "the same result" I mean start with the database at its original state, do the test which can alter the database, and restore the database to its original state.

Up until now, my ideas are:

1. In memory database (which is a Hibernate feature) but that won't allow me to use my actual data.
2. Add "testing flag" to me DOA won't commit the changes if set.

I am sure there is a better solution, but I haven't found anything better yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the database transaction before each test:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em; 

@Before
public void init() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
}

@After
public void destroy() {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

This way, each test has a transaction running before the test starts and this transaction is rolled back after the test finishes, so you always discard all changes the current test underwent.

Comment: at the moment, lets say I want to add user - the add user method create a user instance and call the UserDAO to get session, begin transaction, add the new user, commit the change and close the session. So I don't think I can apply your solution, due to the fact the commit is done during the method.

Comment: If you're doing manual transaction and Session management, then indeed you won;t be able to use this solution. If you were using Spring or Java EE so that you only mark your service methods with @Transactional, this would be a valid alternative.

Comment: Do you think it is better to use Spring or Java EE on top of hibernate? I will look into it anyway, but just as a motivation, what else can I gain by using these tools?

Comment: It's better because they bring you a unified enterprise programming model, that most developers are already familiar with. You get transaction management, AOP/Interceptor support, generic DAOs (Spring Data/DeltaSpike), dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should be clear with the definition of Unit Test. Unit Test must only test a small unit (a public method) in the application.

Assuming you have a DAO layer which uses Hibernate to interact with Database. Now the Hibernate uses a SessionFactory that requires a dataSource. The data source of the Unit Test should not be same as the one for your production application.

The idea is to define a test datasource and use a in memory DB (hsqldb or any other). For each of the test case you can execute some queries on the in memory DB, using the test dataSource and clear that after the execution of the Unit Test. For each Unit Test you should execute the query so that the test data setup is done for that particular test.

For e.g.: If you want to test the following:
1) Create Account
2) Update Account
3) Delete Account

Then there are three test scenarios and there can bee multiple Unit Tests possible for each of the scenario.

Now before executing the Create Account Test, it is important that the DB doesn't have this account. and then you call the createAccount method in the DAO to test the same. No need to verify if the result is in DB or not. Just check the return of your method and if it is same as expected on a successful account creation then your test case should pass.

For Update Account, your setup method should insert one account through query and then you must call the updateAccount in DAO for this account id and so on.

Please stick to the definition of Unit Tests and do not use it for testing more than one functionality at a time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, I am not sure which part of my question gives the impression that I am using unit test for more the one functionality but I assure you this is not the case. What I meant was I already have many unit tests which are already written and I am trying to find a way to modify them so they won't harm the data.
I need this for integration tests as well, and for some tests I prefer to use my existing data instead of using a blank memory database and fill it all by myself, that is why I asked for a method to use my original database and restore it.